# High performance OS/hardware/networking optimizations

Tags: performance, optimization, scheduler, latency

I am working on a very latency sensitive application, and it's at the point where we are trying to get 10s of microseconds of performance improvements out of it. In addition to code optimizations, hardware and OS specific topics have come up, such as [processor affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) and interrupt coalescence.

While this is very useful, I've found that these topics come up as tribal knowledge - someone read an article that mentioned a topic, then we do some research into it, and if it feels promising, we finally try implementing it and measure the results. This feels haphazard to me and I am looking for a more regimented approach to learning about these things. The big problem that I face is not knowing what I don't know.

What is a good approach to learning about lower level OS, hardware and networking specific optimizations? Are there specific books or papers that I should read on the topic, or is it more a matter of reading hardware manuals such as [this one](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html)?

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you have an embedded microcontroller, or a standard "big" PC system? I assume you are concerned about real-time issues, not only about throughput?

Answer (score 0):

Vendors: work with Intel and AMD for processor optimisations, work with RedHat, SuSe, and Microsoft for OS optimisations, subscribe to various mailing lists for development updates on compiler technologies: Clang, and library dependencies: Glibc, etc.

Want high speed networking?  Contact Mellanox, Solarflare, Intel: all are high end vendors and can offer consulting and technology resources for improving development practice and provide insight into future directions.